# getting the instance of controllers Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

So im trying to create my first component and for this ive created the following controller:

```
    <?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die ('Access denied!');
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: Marc
 * Date: 18-08-13
 * Time: 02:18
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );
class MyCompController implements  JController{

    function create(){
        echo "Welcome to create";
    }

    function delete (){
        $id =JRequest::getVar('id');
        echo "you want to delete "-$id;
    }

}
```

Now i am not very familiar with joomla and could only find documentation for 2.5 where

```
$controller = JController::getInstance('MyComp');
```

was a relevant way to get your controller instance.

i looked at the interface and [JController interface](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/controller/controller.php) does not supply a getInstance method because of this i tried:

```
$controller = JController::getApplication('MyComp');
```

But with no luck.

So how do you get the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to accomplish. But I think what you need is in the Joomla 2.5 [tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part).

You need to have a file called `MyComp.php` like they define `HelloWorld.php` in the link above.

That's it. Then when you create a view with some code, say a form:

```
<form action='index.php?option=com_MyComp&task=delete'>
....
</form>
```

This will access your controller's code for the delete function.

On another note, it may be easier to create the template you need for your component with [Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com/). Nice free online tool that builds the template, all the kids use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your component has a bootstrap script with the same name as your component. In your case, that would be `mycomp.php`. That file is included by Joomla, whenever a request with `option=mycomp` occurs. There you setup and call your controller:

```
$controller = new MyCompController;
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```